# it's possible to invert summation/ series limits?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, summation-method

If the summation  just sum every term i was thinking that for instance 1+2+3+4 = 4+3+2+1

so why this $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (3i)\       = \sum\limits_{i=n}^{1} (3i) $$ is not true ?

And how i can invert the limits of the summation without changing the result ?

Comment: Why would you want to "invert the limits of summation" (whatever that may mean)? Can you please provide more context about how this need occurred in your calculations. (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem )

Comment: why is what not true? what are you defining the second one to be? what result is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as others pointed out it is common (not convention) that indexes start from low values to high in that order, but when it is obvious it is undertood

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (3i)\       = \sum\limits_{i=n}^{1} (3i) $ is true, not sure why you think $3+6+9+\cdots +3n \neq 3n+\cdots+9+6+3$?

Just remember it is a shorthand, it is meaningless without defining what it means, you coud even define it with additional properties $\sum\limits_{k \text{ is prime} \le10000} k $  means $2+3+5+7+11+\cdots$ only primes less than 10000.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of convention, indices rise. If you want to reverse the order of the terms, you need to write $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=\sum_{i=1}^na_{n+1-i}$.

Answer (score 1):

To be consistent with the summation identity $\sum\limits_a^{b-1}+\sum\limits_b^c=\sum\limits_a^c$ when $a<b<c$

You need to set $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=M}^m x_i=-\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^{M-1} x_i$ for the case $m<M\ $ (and $0$ if $|M-m|\le 1$).

Have a look at this [paper](http://vixra.org/pdf/1601.0207v1.pdf) for a detailed approach.

As for integrals when bounds are reversed, a negative sign appears before the sum.